# How does one automatically make a `COQ_PROJ.opam` install script automatically from a Coq Project/Package?

Tags: coq, opam

I have [a very long list of coq projects](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/blob/develop/coqgym_projs_splits.json) I want to automatically install with `opam pin/install`. I'd like to install them with opam because I am using [this python tool (PyCoq) that uses opam pin/install](https://github.com/IBM/pycoq/blob/main/pycoq/opam.py#L196). How can I automatically create a `COQ_PROJ.opam / *.opam` file given a coq project that I can install with make?

For example, a format of a coq project/package (proj/pkg) that works for me is this: https://github.com/IBM/pycoq/tree/main/pycoq/test/lf

---

An idea is that in pip one can easily create a pip requirements file from a python project that is already installed ([Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)). Thus, one possible solution could be:

1. install the coq project with make (or it's instructions)
2. run the equivalent of `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but for coq.

How does one do that?

---

sample list of coq projs:

```
[
    {
        "project_name": "constructive-geometry",
        "train_files": [
            "problems.v",
            "affinity.v",
            "basis.v",
            "orthogonality.v",
            "part1.v",
            "part3.v",
            "part2.v"
        ],
        "test_files": [],
        "switch": "coq-8.10"
    },
    {
        "project_name": "higman-s",
        "train_files": [
            "inductive_wqo.v",
            "higman_aux.v",
            "higman.v",
            "list_embeding.v",
            "tree.v"
        ],
        "test_files": [],
        "switch": "coq-8.10"
    },
    {
        "project_name": "int-map",
        "train_files": [
            "Mapcanon.v",
            "Mapc.v",
            "Mapaxioms.v",
            "Map.v",
            "Adalloc.v",
            "Fset.v",
            "Mapsubset.v",
            "Mapfold.v",
            "Maplists.v",
            "Lsort.v",
            "Mapcard.v",
            "Allmaps.v",
            "FMapIntMap.v",
            "Mapiter.v"
        ],
...
```

---

I do know about `opam switch export/import/create` but I doubt it works due to this reason:

```
I think opam switch export assumes that everything I've installed so far was already available in your opam switch already: Save the current switch state to a file.. Thus I think it assumes that you've installed everything so far with opam which is not always true for every coq project afaik and if it were I wouldn't have this issue in the first place -- since I would have used opam pin/install in the first place to install the coq proj/pkg. I think some coq projects/packages use a coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o CoqMakefile followed by a make command (ref: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html#building-a-coq-project, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-installing-external-dependencies-in-a-coq-project). Those that use make are my target. I know make can run arbitrary code but I am hoping there is a standard way to install things in coq that will help me connect it with opam...or python...
```

### though I could try running `make` and then `opam switch export` though I don't know how opam would know how make compiled and got dependencies if `make` uses only `coqc` or something else that doesn't install it to opam...any ideas?

Perhaps useful self contained coq proj/pkg: https://github.com/brando90/pycoq/tree/main/debug_proj though it uses no external dependencies for now :(, help extending it for even the simplest depedency for the sake of example is welcomed!

---

references:

- proverbot's discussion: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/27
- question/discussion in the original coq-gym repo: https://github.com/princeton-vl/CoqGym/discussions/77
- coq projects: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/tree/master/coq-projects
- useful reference for install coq projs: [What is the best practice for installing external dependencies in a Coq project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-installing-external-dependencies-in-a-coq-project)
- gitissue in my PyCoq fork: https://github.com/brando90/pycoq/issues/4
- https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/252087-Machine-learning-and-automation/topic/Installation.20of.20a.20diverse.20set.20of.20Coq.20package.20for.20ML/near/294876190

Comment: How do you know the dependencies of your projects so you can install them with make in the first place?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia great question! I think the assumption I am making is that when `opam` is not used to install things in coq but only `make` there is some sort of common structure to most/many coq projects/packages that we can leverage. So as described in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-installing-external-dependencies-in-a-coq-project the `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o CoqMakefile` followed by `make` might help us locate where the dependencies have been compiled to (plus user standard ways to use coq). I assume `coqc` might also be helpful.

Comment: yes, `make` can run arbitrary code which makes this question in principle impossible, but what makes it trackable is that I that I'm assuming there must be some structure to have coq projects are installed when only `make` (or `coqc`) are used that one can use to create the `coq_pkg_proj.opam` I want to make.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia would they be in the `_CoqProject` file? see a small debug demo I made: https://github.com/brando90/pycoq/blob/main/debug_proj/_CoqProject (though my proj/pkg is so simple it uses no dependencies and it lists only the `*.v` filenames for my proj/pkg.

Comment: In the pre-opam era (which most academic coq projects are stuck in), it's usually up to users to install dependencies, and `coqc` will automatically find installed packages as their modules are `Require`-d. This means dependencies are not recorded anywhere for non-opam users, and `opam` files are precisely where that's done nowadays.

Comment: It might be that most of your packages don't have any dependencies beyond coq and perhaps some widely used packages that you somehow have already installed, in which case the simplest `opam` file would suffice for all of them.